# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3:test (default-test) on project. while 'Run as Maven test'

Tags: eclipse, maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-plugin

I am trying to create my own custom rules for [Z PL/SQL Analyzer plugin by Felipebz](https://felipezorzo.com.br/zpa/). For that, I am following [this](https://github.com/felipebz/sonar-plsql/wiki/Create-a-plugin-with-custom-rules) tutorial.

I downloaded the mentioned [Github Directory](https://github.com/felipebz/sonar-plsql/tree/master/plsql-custom-rules) in that tutorial and imported it in Eclipse. Now, when I try to Run it as "**Maven test**", I get Following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3:test (default-test) on project plsql-custom-rules: There are test failures.
```

There are some more errors in the log:

```
[INFO] Running com.company.plsql.ForbiddenDmlCheckTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.284 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.company.plsql.ForbiddenDmlCheckTest
[ERROR] test(com.company.plsql.ForbiddenDmlCheckTest)  Time elapsed: 0.181 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/assertj/core/api/AbstractStringAssert;
at com.company.plsql.ForbiddenDmlCheckTest.test(ForbiddenDmlCheckTest.java:10)
```

Does someone know any solution to this particular problem?

I want to create a jar for testing it in my SonarQube Server. But, before changing anything in the code, I wanted to test it first as it is; because I reckon that there is a sample rule already provided in the downloaded Project template. I can make further changes in the code once I get to test it as a jar file at first place.

Comment: Seems like depency conflict. Some of the dependencies are importing a different version of org.assertj.core. I think you will have to find wich is and exclude that in the dependecies tag of pom.

Comment: Thanks, Raphael! Actually, my pom.xml didn't have a dependency for org.assertj.core at all. I added it manually and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Raphael Alves suggested, I solved it by adding the following dependency to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
    <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

You might want to check for the latest version of this dependency on [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core)

Answer (score 1):

Carefully check build configuration below, targeted xml that include your test objects name should be correct and commands should correct. Configuration example:

[image: configuration example]

Eg for correct way :

```
clean install -Drelease.testng=inventoryAndWarehouseModuleSmoke.xml
```

This error may also be due to this.

Comment: When adding a link you should try to put a meaningful description to help others understand what they will be looking at when opening it. Edited in that sense.